# Wpf : Livecharts Draw Stacked Column

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am new to wpf and liveCharts, I need to draw something with Stacked Columns and I have no idea how to do it.

This is my specs:

Axis X : days (selected days ) - Axis Y : hours (0-24 h)

I need to represent my activity in days :

Day1 : from 00 am to 08:00 am: Absent (red) - from 09 am to 12 am Activiy 1(green)- from 12 am to 11:00 pm Absent (red).

Day2 : from 00 am to 10 am: Absent (Red) - from 10am to 12 am Activiy 2 (yellow ) etc..

(I also need the blanks area, because sometimes I don't know what happened between 2 activities)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link [Basic stacked column](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Stacked). This will help you understand how to create a basic stacked column chart using live charts. From there I would suggest trying to set up a simple version of what you want and then if you have any issues ask a question with your code and we can try to help.